# Change css with animation when swiper slide is active - Slider Swiper

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

I have 4 slides and want to change background color with fluid animation when slide is changed. There are different colors for each slides. I tried this but it only shows `#available` color when loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Available
if($('#available').hasClass('swiper-slide-active')) {
    $('html').css('background', '#4caf50')
}
//In work
else if($('#inwork').hasClass('swiper-slide-active')) {
    $('html').css('background', '#FFC107')
}
//Pending
else if($('#pending').hasClass('swiper-slide-active')) {
    $('html').css('background', '#ced8d1')
}
//Done
else if($('#done').hasClass('swiper-slide-active')) {
    $('html').css('background', '#7a1e99')
}
})
```

Comment: Your code will gets called only onces ..i.e : when page gets loaded that's the reason only first `if` statement works .

Answer (score 1):

One way of adding a background is to put it in a pseudo element.

You can translate the color settings into CSS so the system will change the colors in a pseudo element when a slide gets the swiper-slide-active class.

Without seeing the full code on the original question it is not possible to assess whether this will interfere with anything else, but try adding this to a style element in head

```
.swiper-style-active::before {
  content:'';
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
}

#available.swiper-slide-active::before {
  background: #4caf50;
}
#in-work.swiper-slide-active::before {
  background: #FFC107;
}
#pending.swiper-slide-active::before {
  background: #ced8d1;
}
#done.swiper-slide-active::before {
  background: #7a1e99;
}
```

Comment: I need the whole body background color to be changed, not active slide

Comment: I have added the css color changes to a pseudo element rather than the element itself it works in my trial, but I don’t know whether it would interfere with anything else in your system.

Answer (score 0):

bind your code to one of the events that will be fired every time a change happens by swiper from [here](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#event-activeIndexChange), for your use case I think `activeIndexChange` would do the job